Two-Line Chart Problem. The two lines are shown connected
I have the following code for making a line chart with two lines:
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct TempView: View {
    let morningTemp: [Data] = morningData(range: range)
    let eveningTemp: [Data] = eveningData(range: range)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Temp, °C")
                .font(.title)
            Chart {
                ForEach(morningTemp) {
                    LineMark(
                        x: .value("Date", $0.date),
                        y: .value("Morning Temp", $0.value)
                    )
                    .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                }
                
                ForEach(eveningTemp) {
                    LineMark(
                        x: .value("Date", $0.date),
                        y: .value("Evening Temp", $0.value)
                    )
                    .foregroundStyle(.red)
                }
            }
            .chartLegend(.visible)
            .chartXAxis {
                AxisMarks()
                {
                    AxisGridLine(centered: true)
                }
                AxisMarks(values: xAxisValues)
                {
                    AxisValueLabel()
                        .font(.system(size: 10, weight: .bold))
                }
            }
            .chartYScale(domain: [36, 40])
            .chartYAxis {
                AxisMarks(values: [36, 37, 38, 39, 40])
                {
                    AxisValueLabel()
                        .font(.system(size: 10, weight: .bold))
                }
                AxisMarks(values: [36, 36.5, 37, 37.5, 38, 38.5, 39, 39.5, 40])
                {
                    AxisGridLine()
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 350)
        }
        
        Spacer()
    }
}

#Preview {
    TempView()
}

This is the result:

The lines are connected instead of being separate.

The first line with the code for the second line commented out.

The second line with the code for the first line commented out.
Why is this happening? I am just starting with Swift and Xcode, so bear with me please.
I tried to find information about the problem online and arrived at the code as shown.
